# Core Image Filter Crash issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I'm trying to load filters for the larger image size of dimensions nearly about 5000*3000 which I have downloaded from Web Search. When applying these filters for the larger image size the app crashes and hence the termination occurs. Below is the code which i'm using currently for the preview of filters :

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter.filter outputImage];
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *displayImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
```

Line of code below is causing the issue, has anyone come across this issue ?

> CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

Answer (score 0):

At this line

> CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

You create a new image reference and then create a new image from this reference

> try to add this line below your last line
>
> CGImageRelease(cgimg)

As ARC did not automatically dealloc this reference so you have to manually release this reference then it will work on your side

Code:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter.filter outputImage];
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *displayImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGImageRelease(cgimg);  // this line release the image reference
```

Comment: I have used the same, it still crashes. For bigger size images it crashes. Dimensions nearly about 5000*3000, did u try bigger image size. It still does not work for me